# Java "Aggregate" Transactions

Tags: java, transactions

Does Java provide a way to intelligently "aggregate" transactions? If I have multiple, heterogeneous data repositories I want to keep synchronized (ie Postgres for data, Neo4j for a graph, and Lucene for an index) is there a paradigm for only allowing N concrete transactions to either succeed or fail, but make sure that they do so consistently (via this "aggregate" transaction)? For example - the Postgres update commits but the Neo4j update fails: the Postgres update gets rolled back, the Lucene update isn't even attempted, and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There is Spring Transaction API framework which allows to aggregate transactions like this. However it doesn't help with partial commit because it is specific for the data sources you use. So the case when the part of the transaction has been committed and part is not will have to be handled in your code.